# (Ruby) Getting internal server error message

Tags: ruby

I've been trying to work out what's going on with my 2 codes but they aren't linking together.

This is my .rb file:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'twitter'
require 'erb'
include ERB::Util

config = {
    :consumer_key =>  '..' ,
    :consumer_secret => '..' ,
    :access_token => '..' ,
    :access_token_secret => '..'
}

client = Twitter::REST::Client.new(config)

get '/following' do
  buddy = client.friends('skg22')
  @follow = buddy.take(20)
  erb :following
end
```

The following.erb file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Twitter Management Interface</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Twitter Management Interface</h1>
<h2>List of Friends</h2>

<% unless @follow.nil? %>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>User</th>
      </tr>

      <% @follow.each do |friend| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= friend.id %></td>
            <td><%= friend.user.screen_name %></td>
          </tr>
      <% end %>
      </table>

    <% else %>
        <p>No friends.</p>
    <% end %>
</body>
</html>
```

I've been driving myself crazy over the past few hours trying to figure out what's the error but every attempts at modification I made doesn't seem to get rid of the error message.

Comment: Does it show you the stack trace?

Comment: Unfortunately, no @August

Comment: Can you post the error message you're seeing?

Comment: The RubyMine console gave me this error, `NoMethodError - undefined method 'user' for #<Twitter::User id=**********>` @messanjah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The .rb file**

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'twitter'
require 'erb'
include ERB::Util

config = {
    :consumer_key =>  '..' ,
    :consumer_secret => '..' ,
    :access_token => '..' ,
    :access_token_secret => '..'
}

client = Twitter::REST::Client.new(config)

get '/following' do
  buddy = client.friends('skg22')
  @follow = buddy.take(20)
  erb :following
end
```

**.ERB file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Twitter Management Interface</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Twitter Management Interface</h1>
<h2>List of Friends</h2>

<% unless @follow.nil? %>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>User</th>
      </tr>

      <% @follow.each do |friend| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= friend.id %></td>
            <td><%= friend.screen_name %></td>
          </tr>
      <% end %>
      </table>

    <% else %>
        <p>No friends.</p>
    <% end %>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message indicates, the `Twitter::User` object does not respond to the method `user.`

Try removing this line in your view:

```
<td><%= friend.user.screen_name %></td>
```

Comment: It worked but I don't understand why the object does not respond to the method `user`. Is there a way or an explanation for that? @messanjah

Comment: The maintainer of the Twitter gem hasn't defined `user` on the User object. The documentation is here: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/REST/Users